# Emma, Geri, Melanie and Victoria form a team to participate in a 4 X 100 metres relay race.

Tags: probability

Emma, Geri, Melanie and Victoria form a team to participate in a 4 X 100 metres relay race. Assume that each of the team members runs the 100 metres in a time (measured in seconds) which has an N(12;0.25) distribution, independently of the others. 
Compute the probability that precisely two of the team members run the 100 metres in more than 12.5 seconds.

I have some problems to solve this question, I think that I have to convert  a standard normal distribution, so then it's possible to have the probability from the table, but the problem is that they said (two of the team members) so I don't know how to include the fact that I have to consider just to of the four team member.

What I did is: $P(X+Y>12.5)=P\big(Z>\frac{val. - \mu}{\sigma}\big)=P\big(Z>\frac{25 - 24}{\sqrt{0.5}}\big)=0.078$

But in the answer, they say that the result is $\left(\begin{array}{c}4\\ 2\end{array}\right) \cdot 0.16^2 \cdot 0.84^2$, where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that you can solve the problem in your way, since it is not possible to have the exactly two constraint there.

The way to solve it is the following. For one runner the probability to run the 100 meter in less than 12.5 seconds is given by $\mathbb{P}(X > 12.5) = 0.84$, where $X \sim N(12, 0.25)$. We can view each runner as one experiment, where the probability of success is 0.84. The number of runners that need more than 12.5 seconds to run the 100 meter is thus given by a binomial distribution, since the runners are independent of each other.

The probability that you want is therefore given by
$$\mathbb{P}(Binom(4,0.84) = 2) = \binom{4}{2} \cdot (1-0.84)^{2} \cdot 0.84^2 = \binom{4}{2} \cdot 0.16^{2} \cdot 0.84^2. $$

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate! It possible that P(X>12.5)=0.16 and not 0.84? But then the result is always the same :)

Comment: That would indeed make more sense :)